# C Primer Plus chapter 6 programming exercise 1

Tags: c

I worked out this problem using what I learned from chapter 6 (current program).  My original idea was to print and scan the values into the array with a loop and them print the values of the array, but I have not been able to make it work (commented section under main function).  The program just prints newlines (the program prints the letter but I have to press enter to get the next letter).  The commented section in the program within the main function is the idea of what I want to do.  I included the program below and I thank you in advance for your help.

```
//This is a program to create an array of 26 elements, store
//26 lowercase letters starting with a, and to print them.
//C Primer Plus Chapter 6 programming exercise 1

#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 26

int main(void)
{
    char array[SIZE];
    char ch;
    int index;

    printf("Please enter letters a to z.\n");
    for(index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
        scanf("%c", &array[index]);
    for(index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
        printf("%c", array[index]);

    //for(ch = 'a', index = 0; ch < ('a' + SIZE); ch++, index++)
    //{ printf("%c", ch);
    //  scanf("%c", &array[index]);
    //}
    //for(index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    //  printf("%c", array[index]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try this `scanf("%c", &array[index]);` --> `scanf(" %c", &array[index]);`

Comment: When you enter the character and then you press enter two characters. One is the character you enter and the other is the `\n`. That's why you get what you see. Solution is to consume the white space charcaters ..which is done by putting the `' '` in the `scanf`.

Comment: @coderredoc, will that also work when entering "`abcdef...`"?

Comment: @coderredoc, sorry, I'm not a scanf guru. Seems the user message is important: `"Please enter letters a to z.` vs. `"Please enter each letter a to z.`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie.: Yes it would work.

Comment: @coderredoc, great. Now the OP doesn't have to write a user manual for this mini-program :-) (and I learned something.)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie.: From standard *A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails.*

Comment: @coderredoc, post as answer?

Comment: The `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful assignments made; check this to be sure that input is as expected. When matches fail, assignments are not made, and using the associated variables can then lead to undefined behavior. _Always_ check the values returned from functions which return meaningful values.

Comment: This is another prime example of the pitfalls of using `scanf` for user input by new C programmers. Before using `scanf` for anything, spend the time it takes to digest the man page, understand *format specifiers* and which consume leading whitespace and which do not,  and the use of  *modifiers* within the *format string* to work around the whitespace problem. Understand how `scanf` process input from `stdin` and what happens to the input if a *matching* or *input* failure occurs. Taking time to understand the basics will save you countless hours of frustration (or just use `fgets` `:)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that

When you enter the character and then you press <kbd>enter</kbd>, you input two characters. One is the alphabetic character you enter and the other is the `\n`. That's why you get what you see. Solution is to consume the white space charcaters ..which is done by putting the `' '` in the `scanf`.

```
scanf(" %c", &array[index]);
       ^
```

Why it works?

Quoting the [standard- **7.21.6.2**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p5)

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
>   reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains
>   unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never
>   fails.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 6

int main(void)
{
    char array[SIZE];
    int index;

    printf("Please enter letters a to z.\n");
    for(index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
        if( scanf(" %c", &array[index]) != 1){
            fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in input");
            exit(1);
        }
        else {
            printf("read: %c\n",array[index]);
        }
    for(index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
        printf("%c", array[index]);

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used scanf("' '%c", &array[index]); and I got the following results:                         
a (program prints a and I press enter) and the program prints the following:  
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`�ަ��@p

Comment: scanf(" %c", &array[index]); only prints the letter a and when I press enter nothing happens.  I am using gcc in Fedora 27 just in case is important and also using --std=c11 when compiling.

Comment: It might be instructive to add an `else printf ("read: %c\n", array[index]);` and also nice to make the output POSIX compliant by adding a `putchar ('\n');` before the `return` `:)`

Comment: I'll find the exact reference, but it basically says all processes shall output a final `'\n'` (so it doesn't mess up my prompt!) [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/contents.html) or [Shell & Utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/contents.html) **note:** it will take me a day or so to find the exact reference in the specification. I think my eyes will glaze over tonight `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: No need to find it..i will get to it. Don't worry.